# Javascript only working when placed below HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I couldn't find a solution for the following problem I'm having. I'm using some javascript code to make my (live) search work (via ajax). The problem is that the Javascript only works when I place it below the HTML:

```
<form action="filter.php" name="filter" method="get" id="filter">
<input type="text" id="search_bar" name="s" placeholder="Type hier je zoekterm..." />
</form>    
<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Javascript

```
$("#filter").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$("#result").html('');
var values = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({        
    url: "tracks_content.php",
    type: "get",
    data: values,
    success: function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
    },
});
 });

 $(this).mouseup(function() {
document.getElementById('result').style.display='none'; 
 });

 $("#result").mouseup(function(){
return false;
 });    

 $("#filter").bind('input',(function(event){
var query = document.getElementById('search_bar').value;
if(query!=""){
    $("#filter").submit();
    document.getElementById('result').style.display='block';
}
else{
    $('#result').html('');
    document.getElementById('result').style.display='none'; 
}
 }));
```

How can I make it work when putting the Javascript in front of the HTML?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are referring to HTML that doesn't exist yet when the JavaScript  is on top.

Wrap your code in `$( document ).ready()`. Thi smakes the browser wait until the DOM is loaded before firing the JavScript.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#filter").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").html('');
    var values = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({        
        url: "tracks_content.php",
        type: "get",
        data: values,
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        },
    });
     });

     $(this).mouseup(function() {
    document.getElementById('result').style.display='none'; 
     });

     $("#result").mouseup(function(){
    return false;
     });    

     $("#filter").bind('input',(function(event){
    var query = document.getElementById('search_bar').value;
    if(query!=""){
        $("#filter").submit();
        document.getElementById('result').style.display='block';
    }
    else{
        $('#result').html('');
        document.getElementById('result').style.display='none'; 
    }
     }));
});
```

FYI, why are you uisng `document.getElementById()` when you have jQuery available to you and are already using it?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! It worked. As an answer to your other question, I don't know another way to do it... Could you maybe tell me how I can do this in a more propriate way?

Comment: This code is actually fine with the exception of not using jQuery to its fullest. In this case just change the references to `document.getElementById()` to `$()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you put that before the HTML, then you are trying to add a submit event to a form which doesn't exist at the time the JavaScript runs.

Wrap the script in a function, then use that function as an event handler for the ready or load event.

Passing a function (instead of a selector, DOM element or strong of HTML) as the argument to `jQuery` will bind as the ready handler.

```
jQuery(bind_form_event_handler);

function bind_form_event_handler() {
    $("#filter").submit(function(event) {
    // etc etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you javascript to this

wrap with $(function(){}

like this

```
$(function(){
    $("#filter").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#result").html('');
    var values = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({        
        url: "tracks_content.php",
        type: "get",
        data: values,
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);
        },
    });
     });

     $(this).mouseup(function() {
    document.getElementById('result').style.display='none'; 
     });

     $("#result").mouseup(function(){
    return false;
     });    

     $("#filter").bind('input',(function(event){
    var query = document.getElementById('search_bar').value;
    if(query!=""){
        $("#filter").submit();
        document.getElementById('result').style.display='block';
    }
    else{
        $('#result').html('');
        document.getElementById('result').style.display='none'; 
    }
     }));

    })
```